# Disable screen capture and allow casting through miracast

Tags: android, miracast

I wanted to make an android app that disables screen capture but allows casting through miracast.

I tried adding FLAG_SECURE to my window but that disabled miracast too. Is there any way that this is possible?

When i try casting my app, the screen blanks out. I have read that flag_secure blocks unsecure displays. How do i allow it to miracast?

MainActivity.java

```
package mallika.nichecomp.in.reminder;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult;
import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    private View view;
    private boolean check, on;
    public WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent (Intent intent) {
       checkNot(intent);
    }
    private void checkNot(Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getStringExtra("reminder_title") != null) {
            final String reminder_title = intent.getStringExtra("reminder_title");
            final String reminder_body = intent.getStringExtra("reminder_body");
            final Integer not_id = intent.getIntExtra("not_id", 999);
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.e("console", "calling jS pushnot");
                    webView.evaluateJavascript("rcd_push_not('"+ reminder_title + "', '" + reminder_body + "', '" + not_id + "')", null);
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);

        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().
                addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                        String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
                        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setToken(newToken);
                    }
                });
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        startWebView();
    }

    private void startWebView() {
        on = true;
        webView.loadUrl("http://nichecomp.co.in/nichecompftp/account/login_reminder.php");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });


        webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        checkNot(getIntent());

        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {

                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                        Uri.parse(url));

                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Service Report");
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mallika.nichecomp.in.homeprogram">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/only_brain"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/only_brain"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Shelves">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".messagingServicess"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post code? Without that is really hard to help you. Please be more descriptive when asking something here :)